# Finding members which are enum

Tags: c#, .net, reflection

I want to do something along the line of this

```
var membersOfTypeEnum =  typeof(myType).GetMembers().Where(i => i.IsEnum);
```

however, in the mockup above `i` is of type `MemberInfo` and does not implement `IsEnum`.

`GetType(i).Name` says `RuntimeType` which is the reflected type that contains the real type (I think), but I cannot seem to find a way to get to the type of the member itself.

So, how do I find members (that are enums) of a given type?

Edit, lets say I want to reflect this type:

```
public static class MyType
{
    public enum EnumMember
    {
        One = 1,
        Two = 2,
    }

   public static string NotEnumMember = "this is a string";
}
```

Comment: by "members" you mean fields? Because Methods and Properties can't be of type enum, only return an enum

Comment: @IlyaIvanov I mean anything returned by GetMembers. GetFields() does not return an enum defined in a class and neither does GetProperties. Nor are they really Methods.. They are just 'members' as far as I can tell.

Comment: members is a generalisation for fields, methods and properties. GetMembers returns them all. What do you want exactly? I don't see how method and property can be of type enum

Comment: @Toodleey enums wrapped in there aren't members.

Comment: @IlyaIvanov I've edited the question to contain a a sample class I want to extract the enums from. the EnumMember is not a part of GetMethods(), GetProperties() or GetFields(), but it IS a part of GetMembers()

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use `GetNestedTypes` to get all nested types and them check if it is a Enum

```
typeof(MyType)
    .GetNestedTypes()
    .Where(type => type.IsEnum)
```

Answer (score 4):

This should do what you're asking - use [`GetNestedTypes`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.getnestedtypes.aspx):

```
var membersOfTypeEnum =  typeof(MyType).GetNestedTypes()
                           .Where(i => i.IsEnum);
```

Live example: http://rextester.com/CGK11010